# I need to create a Box plot from this where Area needs to be on X axis, year wise data needs to be in box plot,

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

**This is my dataframe:**

```
df <- structure(list(Area = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", 
"Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", 
"Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas"), Y1961 = c(9481L, 1706L, 
7488L, 4834L, 92L, 43402L, 0L, 25795L, 22542L, 0L, 138L), Y1962 = c(9414L, 
1749L, 7235L, 4775L, 94L, 40784L, 0L, 27618L, 22627L, 0L, 142L
), Y1963 = c(9194L, 1767L, 6861L, 5240L, 105L, 40219L, 0L, 28902L, 
23637L, 0L, 152L), Y1964 = c(10170L, 1889L, 7255L, 5286L, 95L, 
41638L, 0L, 29107L, 24099L, 0L, 167L), Y1965 = c(10473L, 1884L, 
7509L, 5527L, 84L, 44936L, 0L, 28961L, 22664L, 0L, 173L), Y1966 = c(10169L, 
1995L, 7536L, 5677L, 73L, 46738L, 0L, 30558L, 23785L, 0L, 195L
), Y1967 = c(11289L, 2046L, 7986L, 5833L, 64L, 47437L, 0L, 30443L, 
23949L, 0L, 204L), Y1968 = c(11508L, 2169L, 8839L, 5685L, 59L, 
50357L, 0L, 31344L, 25094L, 0L, 221L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

**I would like to plot:**

`Area` needs to be in x axis and the yearly data needs to be in boxplot.

**I have tried**

using `Area` in x axis. But I am not sure what to include in Y axis here.

I am missing some logic that I don't understand.

**the code i am trying is**

```
ggplot(country_wise_production1,aes(x=Area, y=))+
geom_boxplot(stat = "identity")+ 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

but i am not sure what to include in y axis.

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the code you've tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: hi @RuiBarradas. thanks for your reply. and i am sorry for this confusion. i am new here
ggplot(country_wise_production1,aes(x=Area, y=))+geom_boxplot(stat = "identity")+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
this is the code i am trying, but i am not sure what to include for y axis. Y axis needs to be the given years data here. we cant include multiple columns for y axis. can we?

Answer (score 1):

Please for the future consider the recommendations by Rui Barradas.
As you are a beginner here is how you could do it:

1. bring your data to long format with `pivot_longer`
2. then use `geom_boxplot`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = -Area, 
        names_to = "years", 
        values_to = "values"
    ) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x= Area, y=values)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]